# Amazon Lambda Java function returning png to API gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda

I have a requirement to return a PNG from an Amazon Lambda Java Function to a Amazon Rest API. I have built the function with a function prototype like this:

```
public static void generatePng(InputStream request, OutputStream response, Context context)
```

The InputStream request details the information that needs to be written into the image. The OutputStream response is what is sent back and is a png image. I have tested the code and know that the image encoded in to the output stream is correct as my test writes this to a file which I can see in an image editor.

The issue I have is in the wiring of the response from the Lambda Function to the API gateway. The documents talk exclusively of a String response but my response payload is binary image data.

In the Lambda Integration Response I have tried adding header mappings of:

Content-Length  integration.response.header.Content-Length
Content-Type    integration.response.header.Content-Type

and a body mapping of:
content-type: image/png with a template of $input.body

I have also added a response model of image/png in the Method Response section.

On testing the API, the response to the API call does not show the image though,
but rather a string dump of the image starting with the proper png header:

e.g.: Response Body

```
 ?PNG


 IHDR?
 ??~LIDATx? ...
```

The response headers do show:
    {"Content-Type":"image/png"}

Does anybody know how to configure Amazon API gateway to accept an image as the output of a lambda function call and render it back to the caller properly?

Comment: API Gateway doesn't currently support binary data: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=195218

Comment: In the end I Base64 encoded the image and replied with a JSon payload of the PNG as a base64 encoded image.

Comment: What you could also do is upload the generated PNG to S3 and have your lambda return a 302 redirect to the image via API Gateway. Solved a similar problem like that.

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway doesn't support binary data - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/search.jspa?objID=f199&q=binary&x=0&y=0.

You could consider using the base64 encode/decode feature in the mapping template. [Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html)

Comment: API Gateway has recently added binary data support, haven't found much information online on getting it to work.